# Divi CSS Flex/Margin Error

Tags: css

Coming here since I am out of ideas for debugging.

https://www.biographic.com/the-tale-of-the-trojan-trout/

Starting at 2193px this row shifts from where it originally sits to almost one column over.

Here is the screenshot for the error:

[image]

The rows are all duplicates from each other and there is no custom css inside of this particular row.

I was wondering if anyone had encountered this sort of issue.

I've tried removing margin. using justify/align-items: center. I tried added flex and justify/align-items: center to the parent section but nothing seems to be able to make it readjust.

Any help would be greatly appreciated:) Thanks!

Comment: You should add the code (CSS/JS/HTML, whatever is used t generate what you have here) to your question.  It's substantially more difficult to parse through someone else's code via an image.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TonyDjukic i'm unsure what to post as this is made through the divi page builder. Html, css, and js are all auto generated in bulk

Comment: Your best bet then would be to open a ticket with the Divi support team.